# When to use GridView and ListView in flutter since they do the same thing?

Tags: flutter, dart

What is the differentiation of  `ListView` and `GridView`? `ListView.builder`, `ListView.separated`, `Listview.custom` vs `GridView.builder`, `GridView.count`, `GridView.extent`

Answer (score 1):

## ListView vs GridView

**ListView:** The children are laid out *one-dimensionally* (direction can be horizontal or vertical).

**GridView:** The children are laid out *two-dimensionally*. Even if you don't use the properties that make it visually 2D (by setting `crossAxisCount: 1`), it's still considered 2D.

## Different ListView Constructors

### ListView

```
ListView(
    children: [allItems],
);
```

### ListView.builder

It creates a list of items that are easily generated or otherwise need to be dynamically created.

```
ListView.builder(
    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text("Item $index"),
    itemCount: 10, // not required
);
```

### ListView.separated

Similar to `ListView.builder`. It  takes `itemBuilder` and `separatorBuilder` to create items and separators dynamically.

```
ListView.separated(
    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text("Item $index"),
    separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(),
    itemCount: 10, // not required
);
```

If `itemCount` is not specified, it will create an infinite amount of children as the user scrolls.

### ListView.custom

To use a custom `SliverChildDelegate`. It takes a `childrenDelegate`, which provides the ability to customize additional aspects of the child model.

```
ListView.custom(
    childrenDelegate: mySliverChildDelegate,
);
```

## Different GridView Constructors

### GridView.count

It creates a layout with a fixed number of tiles in the cross axis.

```
GridView.count(
    crossAxisCount: 2, // how many items you want across the grid
    children: [allItems],
);
```

### GridView.extent

It creates a layout with tiles that have a maximum cross-axis extent.

```
GridView.extent(
    maxCrossAxisExtent: 90.0, // maximum space each child can occupy
    children: [allItems],
);
```

### GridView.builder

To create a grid with a large (or infinite) number of children.

Use a `SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount` or a `SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent` for the `gridDelegate` parameter.

```
GridView.builder(
    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
    ),
    itemCount: 6,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return itemWidget;
    }
);
```

### GridView.custom

To use a custom `SliverChildDelegate`.

```
GridView.custom(
    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
    ),
    childrenDelegate: mySliverChildDelegate,
);
```

**Note:**

- Constructors `GridView`, `GridView.builder`, and `GridView.custom` explicitly require a ‘grid delegate’ to be passed to the named parameter, `gridDelegate`.
- While the other constructors, `GridView.count` and `GridView.extent`, create such a class object for you.

**References:**

- Flutter documentation for [ListView Class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html) and [GridView Class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html)
- YouTube videos on [ListView](https://youtu.be/KJpkjHGiI5A) and [GridView](https://youtu.be/bLOtZDTm4H8) by flutter.
- Look at this amazing article for an [in-depth look at the GridView widget](https://andrious.medium.com/decode-gridview-9b123553e604) by Greg Perry.

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same thing.

**ListView** is for one directional way of showing things e.g. list or image carousel.

**GridView** on the other hand is ready for 2D display of things, e.g. for photo gallery .

Comment: and if i want to separate the list,should i use margin after every list?

Comment: You want to seperate lists or elements in list?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the official docs for the difference. Let's see how they're defined in the documentation:

[GirdView.](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html) ([Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bLOtZDTm4H8)):

> A scrollable, **2D array** of widgets.

[image]

[ListView.](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html) ([Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KJpkjHGiI5A)):

> A scrollable list of widgets **arranged linearly**.

[image]